# Processing Multiple sub-directories and all files in each directory

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Hoping someone can help me here, I'm not very familiar with working with directories. My application compresses files and stores them in a media directory as well as stores them in the database, This works well if I create the directory and actually call each file separately.

But I would like to make it dynamic, and process all folders under the install folder, For every directory under this directory I would like to process each directory and all the files within that directory.

What I have tried:

```
public class SetupFiles : ISetupFiles
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;
    private readonly IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    public SetupFiles(ISession session, IFileService fileService, IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _session = session;
        _fileService = fileService;
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }
public void Setup()
    {
        string installPath = ("install/images/");
        _session.Transact(session =>
        {

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(installPath);
            DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = dir.GetDirectories();
            foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
            {
                string currentDirName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                var directory = new MediaCategory
                {
                    Name = subdirectory.Name.ToString().ToUpper(),
                    UrlSegment = subdirectory.Name.Trim().ToLower(),
                };
                session.Save(directory);

                string[] pngFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirName, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                string[] jpgFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirName, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                string[] gifFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirName, "*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirName, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (var currentPngFile in pngFiles)
                {
                    var fileStream = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(currentPngFile).CreateReadStream();
                    MediaFile dbpngFile = _fileService.AddFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(currentPngFile), "image/png", fileStream.Length, directory);
                }
                foreach (var currentJpgFile in jpgFiles)
                {
                    var fileStream = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(currentJpgFile).CreateReadStream();
                    MediaFile dbjpgFile = _fileService.AddFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(currentJpgFile), "image/jpg", fileStream.Length, directory);
                }
                foreach (var currentGifFile in gifFiles)
                {
                    var fileStream = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(currentGifFile).CreateReadStream();
                    MediaFile dbgifFile = _fileService.AddFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(currentGifFile), "image/gif", fileStream.Length, directory);
                }
                foreach (var currentPdfFile in pdfFiles)
                {
                    var fileStream = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(currentPdfFile).CreateReadStream();
                    MediaFile dbgifFile = _fileService.AddFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(currentPdfFile), "file/pdf", fileStream.Length, directory);

                }
            }

        });
    }
```

But for some reason, I get an error that it can not find the directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

int the Line `DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = dir.GetDirectories();` dir shows the directory but `GetDirectories()` returns NULL.

Comment: At what line the exception is thrown?

Comment: `DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = dir.GetDirectories();` is null.

Comment: You get a NullReferenceException then?

Comment: Web returns Can not find the folder, When I step into the application is where I see the subdirectories are Null, if I go to the folder http://localhost/install/images/image.png it will show that image. I am doing something wrong with directoryInfo but just can not seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the wwwroot folder, as IIS does not process that folder in the path, but windows will use the path with wwwroot.

Comment: I am going to try and add the wwwroot to the path and see if it will process properly and let you know.

Comment: So that worked to get the directory files, Now I have a new issue, The file service provider now does not recognize wwwroot folder. >Net Core should have an easier way to work with files within the application.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found my issue. but you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I must have had a Brain Fart. lol With help from @ciubotariu-florin I was able to get past this issue. 
For anyone else with this issue, wwwroot is an environment folder and is part of web root from IIS config. So to work with `Directory()` and or `DirectoryInfo()` you must use `IHostingEnvironment` this allows you to use `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` so changing my path from

```
string installPath = ("install/images/");
```

to

```
string installPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "install/images/").ToLower();
```

solved my issues.